# How to analyze if-expressions in assumptions?

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to prove the following lemma:

```
lemma if_assumption: "(if a = 1 then 2 else 3) = 2 ⟹ a = 1"
  apply (cases "a = 1")
  apply simp_all
```

After simplification I get the following formula:

```
3 = 2 ⟹ a ≠ 1 ⟹ False
```

The result of if-expression equals 2 iff `a` equals 1. So, I guess that I can deduce this fact somehow.

How to prove this lemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is not correct as you wrote it down. Numbers in Isabelle are polymorphic by default (you can check that by hovering over the numbers while pressing Ctrl). There might be a number type for which `3 = 2` holds (e.g. the finite field `{0,1,2}`). In that case, `a` may not be equal to `1`.

If instead you fix the number type:

```
lemma if_assumption: "(if a = 1 then 2 else 3) = (2::nat) ⟹ a = 1"
```

the proof script you wrote goes through. Or shorter:

```
apply (auto split: if_splits)
```

... which tells the system to split the `if _ then _ else _` into two subgoals.

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful for someone. `if_splits` is described in "Concrete Semantics with Isabelle/HOL" book, section 2.5.6 "Case Splitting With simp".